# Why do these two queries return different results in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have written the following query in Entity Framework and the values are different.

```
var query = from p in db.Parents
            let children = p.Children
            let grandchildren = children.SelectMany(c => c.Grandchildren)
            select new 
            {
                Count1 = children.Count(c => !c.Grandchildren.Any()),
                Count2 = children.Count(c => !grandchildren.Any())
            };
```

**The Count1 property returns what I expect, Count2 does not.**

I am trying to return the number of Children that do not have any Grandchild objects. Count2 seems to return 0 in this case, but Count1 returns 1 with the following data set:

Parents

```
Id
------  
1
```

Child

```
Id    ParentId
--------------
1     1
2     1
```

Grandchild

```
Id    ChildId
-------------
1     1
```

I have two children, only one of them has any children. Why does the second query not seem to work the way I think it should?

My objects are as follows:

```
public class Parent {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child { 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Grandchild> Grandchildren { get; set; }
}

public class Grandchild {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grandchildren.Any()
```

is simply returning if there are any objects in your `grandchildren` collection.  So it will always return true unless your `SelectMany` returns zero results.

So, you will never get anything but `Count2 = 0` because if there are any results `!grandChildren.Any()` will equal 0.

Comment: so, !grandChildren.Any() will always return 0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `grandchildren` range variable. It contains *all* grandchildren (*not* filtered to a specific child), so Count2 is always considering if there are *any* grandchildren in the entire tree.